Increase Kubernetes performance
I have a test native Kubernetes installed on a Debian VM. I use it as a test machine for development for 16 Spring Boot microservices.
I use this resources configuration into Helm chart for every Pod:
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 512Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 512Mi

Pods are loading very slow and working very slow. For test env it's working fine but slow. What are the available options to increase the performance?

Dedicated more resources to the pod.

What values update can you recommend to the above without getting too much cluster resources?
